# Ember - Binding to filtered list in array controller, then adding new records

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have [this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/EkUkeki/8/edit) which is using the latest ember and demonstrates my issue.  I have 2 lists.  one is bound to the ArrayController 'content' and the other is bound do a property function called 'filtered' which filters out certain records.  When You add a new record (use the add new link above the lists) you can see that the new record does make it into the content, but the filtered list does not update.  What do I need to do so that the ArrayController will see that there is a new record in the list, and re-render the `{{#each filtered}}` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependent key of your computed property `filtered` is wrong, you need to use `content.length`, because `filtered` depends of some change in `content` property not the filtered itself:

```
filtered:function() {
    return this.get("content").reduce(function (arr, object, index) {
      if(object.get("id") != 2) {
        arr.pushObject(object);
      }
      return arr;
    }, Em.A());
  }.property("content.length")
```

Updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/okAKAnU/1/edit

Comment: yeah, tried, but it said I have to wait 10 minutes... done now, sorry for the delay

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about it. Good to know. I just have made one question and it was downvoted and removed :)

Comment: strangely, the fix works in the jsbin, but not in my app, I'm putting together a new jsbin to see if I can replicate the issue as it's got a bit more to it...